# PHP: TLS socket not setting up using stream_socket_client()

Tags: php, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to open a TLS connection using this code:

```
<?php

$cafile = '/var/www/html/mosquitto/cert.pem';

$socketContext = stream_context_create(["ssl" => [
    "verify_peer_name" => true,
    "cafile" => $cafile
]]);

$socket = stream_socket_client("tls://xx.xx.xx.xx:8883", $errno, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $socketContext);

if (!$socket) {
    print("Error: ".$errstr);
    return false;
}else{
    print("Connection Opened");
}

?>
```

Nginx error log:

```
2018/02/08 17:40:28 [error] 1331#1331: *658 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): SSL operation $
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /var/www/html/test.php on line 10
PHP message: PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/html/test.php on line 10
PHP message: PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tls://xx.xx.xx.xx:8883 (Unknown error) in /var/www/html/test.$
```

This is always getting in error section `!$socket` but without any error string. It's just `Error:`. How can I fix this issue? I'm speculating cert.pem file may be the issue. What file do I need to put there?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing in the server logs?

Comment: @JulienLachal question updated.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix this issue?

That's going to be very hard until you know what the issue is.

Clearly tackling the problem using stream_socket_client is not working *and* is not giving you any useful diagnostic information. You need to breakdown what this call is doing and test each part in isolation.

Does 'xx.xx.xx.xx' represent an IP address or a hostname? If it's the latter you may have issues with resolution. Try [dns_get_record](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)() If its the former, how do you expect to validate the subject of the certificate?

Can you connect on port 8883? Try [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)()

Is SSL working?

- Can you negotiate a cypher
- Is the certificate valid
- is the certificate signed by a CA in your certs.pem file

You can check these from the command line with [openssl s_client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:S_client(1))

**Update**

From your edit: `certificate verify failed` - see note above regarding IP address and certificate vlidation

Comment: xx.xx.xx.xx is the IP. I can connect on port 8883 using python. SSL seems to working everywhere else. Certificate details: Let's Encrypt Authority X3
Identity: Let's Encrypt Authority X3
Verified by: DST Root CA X3
Expires: Wednesday 17 March 2021

Comment: With this certificate two more files were issued, one is private key and other is domain identification. Do I have to use those too?

Comment: NO - PLEASE GO READ UP ON HOW SSL WORKS. You cannot validate an IP address using a certificate. The private key MUST NEVER BE EXPOSED to clients. The PEM file you validate the connection against is that containing the CA, not the server certificate. You need a basic understanding of how the technology works before you can start developing against it.